# Are lunches included when the ship is in port with Costa Cruises?

Tags: food-and-drink, cruising

I'll be going on a Mediterranean [Costa](https://www.costacruises.eu/) cruise soon and I wondered if lunch is included when the ship is in port, or if I have to find a restaurant on shore to have lunch?

I've already been to all the ports this cruise stops at, so I'll probably spend most of the time in the ports on board, enjoying the ship's facilities.

Comment: Have you asked the cruise line itself?

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica their support is closed during weekends if you don't book with the Italian market, so I haven't 

Comment: I can’t speak to Costa specifically but I’ve been on 30+ cruises on 8 of 9 lines and **every** cruise has offered mealtime food while in port. There may be fewer choices and venues open while in port but there will be something.

Comment: @DoxyLover I can now confirm that Costa does offer lunch in while in ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Costa Cruises does serve lunch on board the ships when they are in port, though you can expect almost empty restaurants as most people are on shore.